# Getting XTRE1500 error

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm writing an XSLT and I'm getting the below error.

```
XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Error: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/SG/2016/SICC/XML/XSLT/chapters.xsl:5: Specified URI 'file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/SG/2016/SICC/XML/XSLT/chapters.xsl' is already used for writing -   Details: -     XTRE1500: Cannot write to an external resource and read from the same resource during a single transformation
```

I recently changed my Machine, in my previoys one, there was no issue, in my current system, I'm getting this error.

The error is thrown at

```
<xsl:variable name="ThisDocument" select="document('')"/>
```

In my program I use this as shown below.

```
<xsl:variable name="d">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('toc-item-',$ThisDocument//ntw:nums[@num=$nu]/@word,'-level')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
```

And the ntws is ass below.

```
<!-- Namespace ntw-->
<ntw:nums num="1" word="first"/>
<ntw:nums num="2" word="second"/>
<ntw:nums num="3" word="third"/>
<ntw:nums num="4" word="forth"/>
<ntw:nums num="5" word="fifth"/>
<ntw:nums num="6" word="sixth"/>
<ntw:nums num="7" word="seventh"/>
<ntw:nums num="8" word="eighth"/>
<ntw:nums num="9" word="nighth"/>
<ntw:nums num="10" word="tenth"/>
<!-- Namespace ntw ends -->
```

Here is my full XSLT. http://xsltransform.net/3NJ391b.

I use Altova XML Spy.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting that error on your new machine, but not your old machine. Could be a difference in how the transformation is being run or maybe a difference in versions of XML Spy. Hard to say without being able to reproduce the issue.

What you can try is to not use `document('')`. This isn't necessary since you're using XSLT 2.0.

Try moving your `ntw:nums` elements directly into the `ThisDocument` variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="ThisDocument">
  <ntw:nums num="1" word="first"/>
  <ntw:nums num="2" word="second"/>
  <ntw:nums num="3" word="third"/>
  <ntw:nums num="4" word="forth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="5" word="fifth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="6" word="sixth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="7" word="seventh"/>
  <ntw:nums num="8" word="eighth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="9" word="nighth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="10" word="tenth"/>      
</xsl:variable>
```

You might want to rename the variable and the reference once you've confirmed it's working. I also think it would be a little more specific to add an `as="element()+"` and change the usage.

Here's an example of what I would do...

Replacement for `ThisDocument` variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="nums" as="element()+">
  <ntw:nums num="1" word="first"/>
  <ntw:nums num="2" word="second"/>
  <ntw:nums num="3" word="third"/>
  <ntw:nums num="4" word="forth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="5" word="fifth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="6" word="sixth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="7" word="seventh"/>
  <ntw:nums num="8" word="eighth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="9" word="nighth"/>
  <ntw:nums num="10" word="tenth"/>      
</xsl:variable>
```

Replacement for `d` variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="d">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('toc-item-',$nums[@num=$nu]/@word,'-level')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```